# How do you declare a 2D and 3D List with elements specified in one statement?

Tags: c#, list, declaration

Could someone tell me how I can declare a 2D and 3D `List`, *with* the elements specified in one statement?  I do not want to have them declared later.  The `List` objects are meant to be unchanged.

This is what I am trying to have with a 3D list, but it is not correct:

```
List<string[][]>  List_3D  =  new List<string[][]>    {  {  new string[][]    {  new string[]   {  "A", "B", "C"   },
                                                                                 new string[]   {  "D", "E", "F"   }    },

                                                                                 new string[]   {  "1", "2", "3"   },
                                                                                 new string[]   {  "4", "5", "6"   }    };
```

Comment: @entropic I have edited my question to show what I want to do.

Comment: Looks like chancea beat me to it in the comments.  I believe that is what you're looking for.

Comment: guess I have to read more on http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384062.aspx

Answer (score 2):

All you want is to declare them in one statement, like this?

```
    public List<String> foo = new List<String> { "a", "b", "c" };

    public List<List<String>> foo2D = new List<List<string>> 
    {
        new List<String> {"a", "b", "c"},
        new List<String> {"d", "e", "f"}
    };

    public List<List<List<String>>> foo3D = new List<List<List<string>>> 
    {
        new List<List<String>>
        {
            new List<String> {"a", "b", "c"},
            new List<String> {"d", "e", "f"}
        },
        new List<List<String>>
        {
            new List<String> {"g", "h", "i"},
            new List<String> {"j", "k", "l"}
        }
    };
```

**Edit**

> just curious, how do you declare an outer List with inner string[][]
>   inside?

Basically the same concept, except replace the list with arrays:

```
    public List<String[][]> fooString2D = new List<String[][]>
    {
        new String[][]
        {
            new String[] {"a", "b", "c"},
            new String[] {"d", "e", "f"}
        },
        new String[][]
        {
            new String[] {"g", "h", "i"},
            new String[] {"j", "k", "l"}
        }
    };
```

What is incorrect about your specific code:

- It has an extra `{` right in the beginning
- It is missing the second `new string[][]` declaration
- It needs an extra `}` at the end.

Comment: just curious, how do you declare an outer List with inner string[][] inside?

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're looking for is object initialization. See [Object and Collection Initializers.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384062.aspx)

Here is a simple example:

```
  List<int> myList = new List<int>
        {
            1,
            2,
            3
        };
```